# Keeping track of a pdf viewer spawned via AUCTeX?

Tags: latex, auctex, pdf

When using AUCTeX with pdflatex, one can run `C-c C-c` (`TeX-command-master`) or `C-c C-v` (`TeX-view`) to spawn a PDF viewer.

I use Evince on Debian Wheezy, in case it's relevant.

This might sound a little absurd, but I find it easy to lose track of where the Evince viewer attached to that particular buffer is. Sometimes it can be buried under other windows or mostly off the screen. I run other instances of Evince too. If it makes any difference, I've got Synctex at least partly working.

So, is there some way of telling emacs/AUCTeX to "find" my Evince viewer, or failing that, is there some convenient way to tell emacs/AUCTeX to kill the viewer and start a new one?

Answer (score 2):

#### Linux/UNIX users

I'm guessing that you're going to need control over the window manager in order to find/raise the external PDF window.  Here's a function that depends on the UNIX/Linux command line tool [`wmctrl`](http://tomas.styblo.name/wmctrl/).

The function (minimally tested) will locate the PDF window and raise it, or spawn a new window if it doesn't exist yet.  The initial part of the code cribs directly from `TeX-view`:

```
(defun TeX-view-dwim ()
  "Locate PDF file if open and raise it.  Requires wmctrl."
  (interactive)
  (let ((output-file (TeX-active-master (TeX-output-extension))))
    (when (file-exists-p output-file)
      (let ((code (call-process-shell-command (format "wmctrl -a %s"
                                                      output-file))))
        (cond ((= code 0)               ; pdf has a window, so switch to it
               (message "Switched to pdf file"))
              ((= code 1)               ; pdf not open, so open it
               (message "Opening previously unopened pdf file")
               (TeX-view))
              ((= code 127)             ; wmctrl not installed
               (error "Please install wmctrl to enable this functionality!"))
              (t                        ; Something weird just happened
               (error "Unexpected problem with wmctrl!")))))))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Dan. I thought AUCTeX might have something suitable built in. Apparently not.

Comment: @FaheemMitha: you might also want to check out the [EmacsWiki on Synctex and Evince](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AUCTeX#toc19), which appears to rely on `dbus`.  I've not used `synctex` or `dbus` before, so can't comment on them -- hopefully someone else will provide a more general answer.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to maybe enable SyncTeX using `TeX-source-correlate-mode`. Then the default `C-c C-v` binding will either spawn or raise the Evince window and additionally jump to the current source location.

If you do not want to jump, this function, which is mostly copied from `TeX-evince-sync-view`, will only raise the window (should work on Evince 3.14).

```
(defun TeX-evince-view-dwim ()
  (interactive)
  (require 'url-util)
  (let* ((uri (concat "file://" (let ((url-unreserved-chars (cons ?/ url-unreserved-chars)))
                                  (url-hexify-string
                                   (expand-file-name
                                    (TeX-active-master (TeX-output-extension)))))))
         (owner (dbus-call-method
                 :session "org.gnome.evince.Daemon"
                 "/org/gnome/evince/Daemon"
                 "org.gnome.evince.Daemon"
                 "FindDocument"
                 uri
                 t)))
    (if owner
        (dbus-call-method
         :session owner
         "/org/gtk/Application/anonymous"
         "org.gtk.Application"
         "Activate"
         (list :array :signature "{sv}"))
      (error "Couldn't find the Evince instance for %s" uri))))
```

This causes Evince to send a raise request to your window manager; if the WM does not support this, it won't work.

Comment: What is the `C-c C-v` binding supposed to do, exactly? I tried it, and nothing happened. I *thought* I had synctex enabled. That highlighting thing does work - if I move the cursor in the emacs buffer, and run C-c C-c , the corresponding portion of Evince is highlighted.

Comment: So it is highlighted when you use `C-c C-c` and select the `View` command, but not when pressing `C-c C-v`? That's weird, the latter should be a shortcut for the former.

Comment: Yes, C-c C-v does nothing as far as I can tell. But C-c C-c -> View command: TeX-evince-sync-view doesn't raise the window. It would be nice if it did. It does refresh the highlighting.

Comment: What Evince version and window manager are you using?

Comment: 3.4.0-3.1 (Debian wheezy default) and KDE. I've got a vague feeling I tried to backport something more recent, but ran into problems. Would a more recent version be helpful?

Comment: 3.4 is two and a half years old. At least my code above will likely not work, but otherwise should be fine since `C-c C-c` does what it should. The problem that Evince does not get raised may be due to KDE's focus stealing prevention, which does not allow background apps to suddenly jump to the foreground. You can try to disable that globally in the system settings, but [apparently](http://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/2n9vog/emacsclients_new_frame_doesnt_have_focus/cmdgozw), it is also possible to do that on a per-app basis.

Comment: I see. Thanks, Chris, I might try configuring KDE on a per-app basis.

Comment: Actually, maybe that is why C-c C-v does not work. Maybe it is only available in more recent versions of Evince.

Comment: No, that's an Emacs thing. It should be equivalent to `C-c C-c`,  `View`.