# AUCTeX's pdf viewer doesn't open when Hebrew is the default polyglossia language

Tags: auctex, latex, bidirectional-support

Consider the following LaTeX document.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\iffalse
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\fi

\begin{document}

Hello, world!

\end{document}
```

After finishing writing the document, I hit `C-c RET` twice.

1. Scenario 1 - with the `\iffalse ... \fi` as shown

   After the first time the message `LaTeX: successfully formatted {1} page` appears in the echo line. After the second time the message `View command: TeX-evince-sync-view` appears in the echo line. If I now hit `RET`, a pdf viewer opens with the processed document.
2. Scenario 2 - without the `\iffalse` and without the `\fi` tags

   After both the first and the second time the message `You should run LaTeX again to get references right, {1} page` appears in the echo line. The pdf file is created and, when opened manually, looks fine, but the pdf viewer does not open from within Emacs as in scenario 1.

How can I get the same behavior of scenario 1, specifically the automatic opening of the synched pdf file, under the setup of scenario 2?

Comment: I'm speculating that it's some hang-up since you have to use `xetex` or `luatex`.  However, the simplest thing to do would simply be to use `C-c C-v` (`TeX-view`) after you've compiled the file.

Comment: @Dan: Thank, Dan. `C-c C-v` has no effect.

Comment: Did you compile it first (eg, with `C-c C-c`)?  After I compile, I get the "You should run LaTeX again..." message to which you're referring, but `C-c C-v` opens the viewer right up.  (Note, also, that you can `C-c C-c` and select `View` and it should do the same thing.)

Comment: @Dan: I compiled it first to no avail. The toolbar `View` button doesn't work either. When clicked, the message `tool-bar view-` appears in the echo line, and nothing more. In particular, the pdf viewer does not open. The same behavior registers (both when using the keyboard shortcuts as well as when clicking the button) when the `\iffalse ... \fi` directives are in place.

Comment: Can you check to make sure that compiling actually produced a pdf for the file?  FWIW, you may want to `(setq TeX-PDF-mode t)`.

Comment: @Dan: Oops, sorry. My bad. `C-c C-v` does work. It's just that the pdf viewer had already been opened and `C-c C-v` didn't push it to the foreground, so I didn't notice it. Sorry. Thanks.

Comment: Good to hear that it's working.  As an aside, you may be interested in [Keeping track of a pdf viewer spawned by AUCTeX](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/5870/keeping-track-of-a-pdf-viewer-spawned-via-auctex/5871#5871).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Converting running comments to an answer.)

This is a partial solution.  It's unclear why AUCTeX perpetually tells you "You should run LaTeX again..." after compiling (but I can confirm that it happened for me as well).  Best guess is that it's something about the fact that `polyglossia` requires either `xetex` or `luatex`, and perhaps the latter don't play as well with AUCTeX as does `latex`.

However: after you compile and create a PDF (to keep it automatic, make sure to set `TeX-PDF-mode` to `t`), you can force AUCTeX to display the PDF in one of two ways:

1. `C-c C-v` (`TeX-view`) will open your viewer;
2. `C-c C-c` (`TeX-command-master`) allows you to type `View` and then opens your viewer.

Comment: In the output log there is always the line `LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.`, that's why AUCTeX always suggest to rerun the compiler.  There is something weird in some of the loaded packages, it's not AUCTeX' fault.

Comment: @giordano: right, I'm speculating that `xetex` or `luatex` is having trouble keeping track of labels, which is why AUCTeX is doing what it does.